# Append record onto RecordArray and Dynamically update Component Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here is what the rendered component looks like:

[image: Rendered component]

What I expect is that when I click that "Add an object" button, it creates a new `Rental` record, and it appends that `Rental` record to the existing `RecordArray`.  Since that `RecordArray` is tracked, the component template re-renders, and thus the new record's `title` attribute displays in the template.

When I click the Button, it returns this error in Web Inspector:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.myrentals.pushObject is not a function at MyCompComponent.addRental

For the base setup of the app referenced in this question, I am using the [Ember Guides Tutorial App](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-2/recap/).

Here is the route specified in my `router.js`

```
// router.js
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('testing');
});
```

Here is my route which returns a `RecordArray` of `rental` records:

```
// testing.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class IndexRoute extends Route {

  @service store;

  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('rental');
  }
}
```

Here is my `rental` model:

```
// rental.js
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class RentalModel extends Model {
  @attr title;
}
```

My `testing` template:

```
//templates/testing.hbs
<MyComp @rentals={{@model}} />
```

My `MyComp` component template:

```
// components/my-comp.hbs
<h2>Practice Iterate over RecordArray and Add items</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each @rentals as |rental| }}
    <li>{{rental.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<button type="button" {{on "click" this.addRental}}>Add an object</button>
```

Lastly, my accompanying `MyComp` component class:

```
// components/my-comp.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default class MyCompComponent extends Component {
  @tracked myRentals = this.args;

  @action
  addRental() {
    this.myRentals.pushObject({
      title: "My new rental"
    });
  }
}
```

I did reference the [Ember JS Looping Through Lists Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/looping-through-lists/). I am clearly missing one or more concepts at work here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Here is the component template:

```
//components/my-comp.hbs
<h2>Practice Iterate over RecordArray and Add items</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each this.myRentals as |rental| }}
    <li>{{rental.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<button type="button" {{on "click" this.addRental}}>Add an object</button>
```

And here is the component's class:

```
// components/my-comp.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class MyCompComponent extends Component {
  @service store;
  @tracked myRentals = this.args.rentals;

  @action
  addRental() {
    this.myRentals.pushObject(this.store.createRecord('rental', {title: "test"}));
  }
}
```

There were a couple of details I needed to correct:

- I had to inject `store` and then set it as a property.
- In order to grab the `rentals` variable that is passed in as an argument into the `my-comp` template, I needed to grab it by `this.args.rentals`.
- In order to append to the `RecordArray` of `Rental` records, I had to instantiate the `rental` record with `this.store.createRecord`.

I hope this helps others!